# Class exported to dll have no constructor body

Tags: c#, class, dll, constructor

Meeting an issue when compiling a dll with a single POCO inside, let's say:

```
public Person
{
    public Guid PersonId { get; set; }
    public Person()
    {
        this.PersonId = Guid.NewGuid();
    }

}
```

When I connect compiled dll to another project, my class looks like

```
public Person
{
    public Guid PersonId { get; set; }
    public Person();
}
```

Where is the constructor body? Did I miss something?

P.S. Project Runtime is v.4.5, while DLL's is v4.0

Comment: Are you taking about metadata?

Comment: if you instantiate  the class, do you have value for `PersonID`?

Comment: you should make the PersonId private aswell, there's little use in making it public in this implementation

Comment: @491243 - That's the point - I dodn't. Value is not generating.

Comment: @Thousand - Why? That's the idea of c# properties.

Comment: @Rahul, Hey thanks! That did the trick. But I've changed DLL target framework to 4.5

Comment: @linuxod, Hey man ... I have made that as an answer. What I mean is ... change the target framework to 4.0 or 4.5 for both class library and your consumer application.

Answer (score 2):

You aren't actually looking at source code with the Object Browser, only the metadata which describes member signatures.

So it's perfectly normal to only see member signatures.

To see code inside methods, you'll need to use a disassembler like `ildasm` or dotPeek or Red Gate Reflector.